# How to Deployment My Bot

Tags: deployment, einstein, einstein-chatbot

I have a bot, this bot doesn't exist in production org and I am trying to upload my bot in production org but I cannot, he give an error:

```
Invalid action reference: null
```

My change sets:

[image]

Response:

[image]

Please, help me. **(I already try in Workbench, but give the same error.)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how are you?
this link solve my problem: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000C6At9SAF

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.